# Passing UPN as NameIDd if Identity is different email

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, adfs, adfs4.0

Our `UPN` and `primary SMTP` are different and since the parent company controls that aspect of the environment I cannot change that.

```
UPN: name@parentcorp.com
Email: name@childcorp.com
```

I have an on-prem ADFS 4.0 server which we have complete control over and so far we have about 12 website/apps setup which all work fine.

In every instance so far the website has a field for `"email"` and a separate field I can use for `"federation ID"` which I populate w/ the `UPN`.
Then I setup my claims to accept the `UPN as NameID` and everything is normal.

Now I have to setup two new sites which don't give me that option however I have to put in the `Primary SMTP` into the email field and that is the only field I can pass to my claim.

I'm wondering if it's possible for our users to still sign in using `name@parentcorp.com` even though the email is `name@childcorp.com`.

Normally I would think this would be possible but I read an *MS article about configuring an alternate logon ID* and thought that might be possible. Or using the *Transform Incoming Claim* option under the Claim Policy section.

Answer (score 0):

Both are possible but they are different use cases. One is authentication; one is claims.

You can use any AD field for AlternateID.

And yes, you can use a Transform claim.

Need more detail as the exact requirement.